# Tkinter ValueError when converting seconds to minutes?

Tags: python, tkinter, timer, valueerror

So, I'm working on a timer using Python and Tkinter's GUI. To do so, I intend to convert the minutes into seconds (as seen in my code) and use Python's time.sleep command to count down (not yet implemented).

```
from tkinter import *
import time
countdown = Tk()
countdown.geometry('500x300')
minute = Text(countdown, height = 0.01, width = 5)
minute.place(x=100, y=100)
minlabel = Label(text = "Input Minutes", font = ("MS Sans Serif", 10), bg = 'Light Blue')
minlabel.place(x=85, y = 80)
def go(event):
    minseconds = int(minute.get("1.0", END))*60
    print(int(minseconds)) 
countdown.bind('<Return>', go)
countdown.mainloop()
```

However, when I convert it to minutes, it works the first time (I.E, when I input 3, 180 returns), but any time after that I get this:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3\n3\n\n'
```

Any idea what could be causing this? And why it works the first time but then stops working? Thanks :)

Comment: this `'3\n3\n\n'` contains more than numbers. `'\n'` means a line break point, you need to filter the string in the way you want to work with. Maybe dont use `tk.END` rather an known index.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is every time <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed a newline character is entered into the `Text` widget named `minute` and they mess up the conversion to `int`.

The simplest way I can think of to avoid that would be to just clear the widget in the event handler function:

```
def go(event):
    minseconds = int(minute.get("1.0", END))*60
    print(int(minseconds))
    minute.delete('1.0', END)  # <---- ADDED.
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this update function. Import the module at top

```
import messagebox as msg
def go(event):
    try:
        minseconds = int(minute.get("1.0", END))*60
        print(int(minseconds)) 
        minute.delete("1.0", END)
   except Exception:
        msg.showerror("Error","invalid input provided.")
        minute.delete("1.0", END)
```

But I would suggest to go with Entry With a `StringVar()`

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as msg
countdown = Tk()
countdown.geometry('500x300')
minute=StringVar()
minut = Entry(countdown,textvariable=minute, width = 5)
minut.place(x=100, y=100)
minlabel = Label(text = "Input Minutes", font = ("MS Sans Serif", 10), bg = 'Light Blue')
minlabel.place(x=85, y = 80)
def go(event):
    try:
        minseconds = int(minute.get())*60
        print(int(minseconds)) 
        minute.set("")
    except ValueError:
        msg.showerror("Error","Invalid input provided.")
countdown.bind('<Return>', go)
countdown.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

so actually the error is quite simple. You created a Text widget, which is just adding lines when you press Enter (corresponding to the \n characters). Just make your text widget bigger (instead of height = 0.01 maybe 2) and you will see it.

To do it more elegantly, you might try Entry() instead of Text(). See the example.

```
import time
import tkinter as tk

def go(event):
    minseconds = int(min_entry.get())
    seconds = minseconds*60
    print(int(seconds))

countdown = tk.Tk()
countdown.geometry('500x300')

minlabel = tk.Label(text = "Input Minutes", font = ("MS Sans Serif", 10), bg = 'Light Blue')
minlabel.place(x=85, y = 80)
min_entry = tk.Entry()
min_entry.place(x=100, y=100)

countdown.bind('<Return>', go)
countdown.mainloop()
```

Furthermore try to put your functions always on top of your code, as they have to be defined before you call them. This might be causing trouble as you code gets bigger.

Hope you get a better understanding from tkinter by this :)